# HTML 5 elements overlap

Tags: css, html

I have two pages that should display the same, but on the second one the legend under the schedule overlaps the "Promotions" box underneath. Anybody spot where i have failed?

here's the page where it works properly:

http://www.bikramyoga.cz/schedule.htm

and here's the page where I have overlap:

http://www.bikramyoga.cz/schedule_5.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the overlapped page, the div with id="content" has a fixed height, remove that CSS rule and it will work.

find it in bkstyle.css line 345.

A fixed height will make the rest of the content, the content that does not fit inside, to overflow.

Comment: thanks, I have to keep the #content fixed, but I did take back the padding in the table, which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work if you remove

`height:510px;`

from

`#content`

*Tested in Chrome*